# How many iterations does assembly cmp make on average?

Tags: math, assembly, statistics

Let's imagine cmp takes 2 same-sized registers and starts comparing them by their MSBs, if they are equal, by the next bit, and so on. What is the average number of bit comparisons before we know which register holds larger value?

Would appreciate the process of solving, or at least answers for 2, 4 and 8 byte registers.

Comment: That's not how cpus do it, but sure, let's imagine :) My gut feeling is that the number of comparisons for uniform distribution should be `n/2`.

Comment: the `cmp` instructions perform a subtraction of the operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can stop as soon as the two bits are different.

Chance of stopping after 1st iteration: 1/2 (We stop if 0-1 or 1-0. We must continue if 0-0 or 1-1.)

Chance of stopping after 2nd iterations: chance of continuing after first iteration * 1/2 = 1/4

Chance of stopping after 3rd iterations: 1/8

Chance of stopping after 4th iterations: 1/16

Chance of stopping after nth iterations: 1/(2^n)

Expected number of iterations for n bits:
(1 * 1/2) + (2 * 1/4) + (3 * 1/8) + (4 * 1/16) + ... + (n * 1/(2^n))